# Layout and admin don't work after first install in local VM

Tags: magento2, layout, installation

I've created an Ubuntu 16.04 VM in Virtualbox with MySQL, Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.0, everything default. Then I installed Magento 2.0 via de CLI, using this [Linode manual](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/ecommerce/install-magento-on-ubuntu-16-04). At the end of the script, it gave an admin URL, which didn't work. If I open the homepage, I see text, but CSS and pictures are not loaded. Access and error log don't show anything.

I reverted to a previous snapshot, before installing Magento, and reinstalled it. Nothing changed. I tried this in a Centos 7 VM, same story.

Is there a way to repair this?

Comment: Why do you not simply use the Magento DevBox? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/docker/docker-over.html

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about this. I've installed it and have it running now. It only gives options for Mac and Windows. Does that work with Ubuntu as well?

Comment: I don't know, I would try the mac version then. Can you give an update when you tried it? :)